# pandas pivot_table returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count, pivot-table

I get an empty dataframe when I try to group values using the pivot_table. Let's first create some stupid data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"size":['large','middle','xsmall','large','middle','small'],
                   "color":['blue','blue','red','black','red','red']})
```

When I use:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='size', aggfunc='count')
```

returns me what I expect. Now I would like to have a complete pivot table with the color as column:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='size', aggfunc='count',columns='color')
```

But this results in an empty dataframe. Why? How can I get a simple pivot table which counts me the number of combinations?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use len as the aggfunc, like so

```
df.pivot_table(index='size', aggfunc=len, columns='color')
```

If you want to use count, here are the steps:

1. First add a frequency columns, like so:

   ```
   df['freq'] = df.groupby(['color', 'size'])['color'].transform('count')
   ```
2. Then create the pivot table using the frequency column:

   ```
   df.pivot_table(values='freq', index='size', aggfunc='count', columns='color')
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you need another column to be used as values for aggregation.

Add a column -

`df['freq']=1`

Your code will work.